# How to edit and get the updates of the editText input fields from another activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm trying to play around with two activities. Edit and View activity. I would like to get the inputs from the edit activity and show in the view activity. In the edit activity I have the ok/submit button, which approves the changes and take back to the view activity, in this case the input text fields should be updated with the entered data. If the cancel button is pressed, then obviously no changes being done and the user is being taken back to the view activity.

I've most of the implementations done right, but I can't get the entered data to be shown on the view activity. What am I missing?

This is my codes for edit and view activities.

ViewActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_FNAME = "EXTRA_TEXT";
    public static final String EXTRA_LNAME = "EXTRA_TEXT";
    public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "EXTRA_TEXT";

    String Fname, Lname, email;
    EditText FNInput, LNInput, emailInput;
    Button editButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

        FNInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FNInput);
        LNInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LNInput);
        emailInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);

        editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openEditActivity();
            }
        });

        Fname = FNInput.getText().toString();
        Lname = LNInput.getText().toString();
        email = emailInput.getText().toString();
    }
    public void openEditActivity(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FNAME, Fname);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LNAME, Lname);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

EditActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_FNAME = "EXTRA_TEXT";
    public static final String EXTRA_LNAME = "EXTRA_TEXT";
    public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "EXTRA_TEXT";

    String Fname, Lname, email;
    EditText FNInput, LNInput, emailInput;
    Button okButton, cancelButton;

    private static final String TAG = "EditActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        FNInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FNInput);
        LNInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LNInput);
        emailInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updateViewActivity();
            }
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FNInput.setText("");
                LNInput.setText("");
                emailInput.setText("");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateViewActivity(){
        Fname = FNInput.getText().toString();
        Lname = LNInput.getText().toString();
        email = emailInput.getText().toString();

        FNInput.setText(Fname);
        LNInput.setText(Lname);
        emailInput.setText(email);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FNAME, Fname);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LNAME, Lname);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="374dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/FNInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LNInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="info@mail.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okButton"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewTV"
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="View Activity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="687dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_edit.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="374dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/FNInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LNInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="info@mail.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/okButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#03A9F4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewTV"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="169dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="Edit Activity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry this post is going to be lengthy.
When you want to do something like this, you have to follow some steps and follow them properly. which are:-

- **First**, making yourself clear what you want to do exactly, that mean your **goal**.
- **Secondly**, try to understand what you should do to achieve that goal, like - what thing might have need to do that, resources, tutorial (for this scenario) etc.
- **Finally** let's start searching and learn how to do that.

**Here,** I can tell you where the problem is, you started learning but didn't completed the learning. I can see you just copied and pasted into **two different activities** without a reason.

Well, I am sharing what problems I found out from the above code of yours :-

1. Your `ViewActivity.java` should be consist of some `TextView` where you're intended to show your data from your `EditActivity.java`, which is not there.
2. You're sending Data with same `key` every time (another proof of copy pasting, not knowing what is happening) which is -

   `public static final String EXTRA_FNAME = "EXTRA_TEXT"; // use it as EXTRA_FNAME  public static final String EXTRA_LNAME = "EXTRA_TEXT"; // use it as EXTRA_LNAME public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "EXTRA_TEXT"; // use it as EXTRA_EMAIL`
3. When you are sending data to your view activity, you need to receive what you were sending by using `getIntent()` something like :- `String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_FNAME");` which will return the value assigned to this `key` from your previous activity while sending to the present activity.
4. After receiving the desired value populate your `TextView` in the next line like this :- `textView.setText(s); // fetched from getIntent() previously`

For more information you can check [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-send-data-from-one-activity-to-second-activity/), which has showed how to pass and view data from one activity to another. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is indeed a great help to have a strategy when building or solving something. The link helped me understand the process. I wasn't very sure with the receiving part. Still not very sure why putExtra() funciton should be used like that.

Comment: Assuming that you are known about how `HashMap` works, yes it works as `key - value` pair. You can relate the situation. Here -

**putExtra() :** This method is basically used for putting data/value into an intent map which you are sending to your receiver activity like `intent.putExtra("key","value")`.
**getStringExtra() :** So, you have sent the data to your next activity, how will you receive that data? well, you need to get the intent first, then get the respective data with it's type like `getIntent().getStringExtra("key")`. 
Hope you understand.